# Tkinter.Tcl().eval() uses wrong Tcl version

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I need to run some Tcl scripts from Python.
Tcl scripts use some 8.5 version specific features, so I cannot use tcl 8.4 version

Now this is this problem.
As you can see - Python runs right Tkinter version, but eval() calls to tcl8.4

```
~ $ ipython
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 26 2014, 17:32:04)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import Tkinter

In [2]: Tkinter.Tcl
Tkinter.Tcl         Tkinter.TclError    Tkinter.TclVersion

In [2]: Tkinter.TclVersion
Out[2]: 8.5

In [3]: Tkinter.Tcl().eval("info tclversion")
Out[3]: '8.4'
```

Googled all day long without results.
Thank you for help.

Comment: On my system, I got 8.5 for both. OS X 10.9.2, Python 2.7, Tcl 8.5

Comment: What do you see when you try this: `Tkinter.Tcl().getvar('auto_path')` ? Is it the same as what you get when you fire up `tclsh` ?

Comment: In [4]: Tkinter.Tcl().getvar("auto_path")
Out[4]: ('/usr/share/tcl8.4', u'/usr/share', '/usr/lib64')

Comment: Looks like a Python bug to me; they shouldn't be using Tcl 8.4 any more as that's unsupported.

Comment: Did you install Tcl 8.5 after you installed Python?  Python seems to configure the Tcl version it will use upon install, so you may need to uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: FYI, you can get the exact tcl version and patchlevel with `tk.Tcl().call("info", "patchlevel")`.